# The correct way to get results in Generate series in postgres for time

Tags: postgresql, date, generate-series

I want to use generate_series function in postgres so that I can get data like this, the idea is to get range interval with 1 second substraction

```
[
        {
            "generate_series": "2021-09-24T19:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "generate_series": "2021-09-24T19:14:59.000Z"
        },
        {
            "generate_series": "2021-09-24T19:15:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "generate_series": "2021-09-24T19:29:59.000Z"
        },
        {
            "generate_series": "2021-09-24T20:30:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "generate_series": "2021-09-24T20:44:59.000Z"
        },
        {
            "generate_series": "2021-09-24T20:45:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "generate_series": "2021-09-24T20:59:59.000Z"
        }
    ]
```

I use this formula, `SELECT * from generate_series(('02:00:00'::time + '2021-09-25'::date)::timestamp,('04:00:00'::time + '2021-09-25'::date)::timestamp, interval '15m');`

However, this is the result that I get

```
[
        {
            "generate_series": "2021-09-24T19:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "generate_series": "2021-09-24T19:15:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "generate_series": "2021-09-24T19:30:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "generate_series": "2021-09-24T19:45:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "generate_series": "2021-09-24T20:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "generate_series": "2021-09-24T20:15:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "generate_series": "2021-09-24T20:30:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "generate_series": "2021-09-24T20:45:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "generate_series": "2021-09-24T21:00:00.000Z"
        }
    ]
```

How do I achieve the first result using generate_series in postgres?

Comment: see docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-srf.html

Comment: why do you want/need a "1 second substraction" ??

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  g - (CASE WHEN r>1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  * INTERVAL '1 SECOND') 
from (
   select 
      row_number() over (order by generate_series) r, 
      generate_series g 
   from generate_series('2021-09-24T19:00:00.000Z'::timestamp, '2021-09-24T20:59:59.000Z'::timestamp,INTERVAL '15 minutes')
) as x;
```

output:

```
      ?column?
---------------------
 2021-09-24 19:00:00
 2021-09-24 19:14:59
 2021-09-24 19:29:59
 2021-09-24 19:44:59
 2021-09-24 19:59:59
 2021-09-24 20:14:59
 2021-09-24 20:29:59
 2021-09-24 20:44:59
(8 rows)
```

If you want the output in JSON format:

```
select json_agg(x) from (
    select 
  g - (CASE WHEN r>1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  * INTERVAL '1 SECOND') as "generate_series"
from (
   select 
      row_number() over (order by generate_series) r, 
      generate_series g 
   from generate_series('2021-09-24T19:00:00.000Z'::timestamp, '2021-09-24T20:59:59.000Z'::timestamp,INTERVAL '15 minutes')
) x ) x;
```

output:

```
[{"generate_series":"2021-09-24T19:00:00"},
 {"generate_series":"2021-09-24T19:14:59"},
 {"generate_series":"2021-09-24T19:29:59"},
 {"generate_series":"2021-09-24T19:44:59"},
 {"generate_series":"2021-09-24T19:59:59"},
 {"generate_series":"2021-09-24T20:14:59"},
 {"generate_series":"2021-09-24T20:29:59"},
 {"generate_series":"2021-09-24T20:44:59"}]
```

Comment: This one is almost correct

Comment: What do you mean by "almost correct"? Is it the fact that it is not in JSON format?  (edit in a few seconds)